# REGEX to match a string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match string on statement

Need a single regex(perl) to match `123` in following condition

1. `TEST|^~\&|NET^OPT|123^FL|`
2. `TEST|^~\&|NET^OPT|123|`

Comment: what is the string and what do you want to match? Provide some test cases and also use code formatting.

Comment: regex to match "123" in the given statements 1 and 2

Comment: what exactly do you want to match ? jsut 123 or 123 along with letters or 1letters23 or ... ?? please make it clear !

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as `^(?:[^|]+\|){3}(\w+)` should work. All you need to make sure is to escape a bunch of the characters.

```
^(?:[^|]+\|){3}(\w+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/gG4aM2)

Comment: check out OP's comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327419/regex-to-match-a-string?noredirect=1#comment33930723_22327419

Comment: what if we have statements like  1)TEST|^~\&|NET^|12we3^FL|TEST|
2)TEST|^~\&|run^NwT|12we3|asdf|...how will you match 12we3...note 12we3 will not be same always..it may be some alphanumeric(like tes1123,ssd12)

Comment: @JagadeeshKumarS Feel free to change `\d+` to `\w+` to match alpha numeric characters.